# Rails how to write Bootstrap popover in an index file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap popover working in a Rails form:

```
    <%= f.input :r_desc, :label => 'Description', :input_html => {:rows =>   '10', :class => "span8", "data-content" => 'Uses Textile styling', "data-title" =>   'TEXTILE'} %>
```

That uses the :input_html to place the popover contents.

But, how do I write one into a Rails index line?

```
        <td><%= screencast.desc  %></td>
```

I'd like to add this to the screencast.desc:

```
rel="popover" data-content="<%= screencast.desc %>" data-original-title="Description">
```

But, I'm not sure how to place that code into the screencast.desc display code.

Thanks!

Update -----
This works - but, it's not exactly what I want.  It turns the data field into a button.

```
        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-large" rel="popover" data-content="<%= screencast.desc %>" data-original-title="Description"><%= screencast.title %></a></td>
```

Update 2 ----   THIS WORKS!

```
    <td><a rel="popover" data-content="<%= screencast.desc %>" data-original-title="Description"><%= screencast.title %></a></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
 <td><a rel="popover" data-content="<%= screencast.desc %>" data-original-title="Description"><%= screencast.title %></a></td>
```